# Django per-site caching and Vary: Cache

Tags: django, caching, nginx, django-views

I noticed that my per-site caching does not work because page response headers include:

```
Vary:Cookie
```

Since I have google analytics installed it will update cookie on every page load which would make cache unusable.

I am not sure if I have added Vary:Cookie to page response headers implicitly or where it comes from. Any help appreciated.

Django 1.3.1

**UPDATE:**

it turns out that when `session` middleware is included and `session` is accessed, it will add `Vary:Cookie`header to response. In my case reason is that 3rd party app is accessing session.

Comment: how did you solve this (separate question really)? Did you have to get rid of google analytics?

Comment: This was for FeinCMS, I filled an issue but did not receive any confirmation or reply yet. If you are interested: https://github.com/feincms/feincms/issues/228

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not really formulated as a question :) but I thought I would point out a few things.

[Django cache is **not** sensitive to cookies by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers). But you can tell him to be by setting the `vary_on_*` decorators.

This means that the per-site cache you are talking about is something else - you mention google analytics, though it's not really clear how related that is to caching itself.

Thus you probably (?) have some caching fronted.

If you were to be using [**nginx**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache) or [**varnish**](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/vary.html), you can customize the way `vary` affects the cache, and with nginx you can also remove it from the response so that the client does not receive it (including google analytics).

If you simply want javascript not to see the session cookies, there's a specific setting: `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`.

You should have a per-url-pattern strategy where you adapt cache behaviour to pages that depend, or not, to a logged-in user, by using or ignoring the Vary and Expire headers.

**[edit]**

### using Nginx for caching

If you are using nginx as a frontend and want to cache with it, there's a very simple way to force caching for views where the cookies are unnecessary using :

```
location /yourpath/ {
    proxy_cache cache_name;
    proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1d; # how long the nginx cache will last
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri$cookie_user"; # you can still use /one/ cookie for your cache!

    ...
    proxy_pass @namedlocation;
}
```

you will need to define a cache, for more information checkout: https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy

With uwsgi very similar settings apply, just they are prefixed uwsgi; checkout the [uwsgi doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule), but considering it is less verbose than the "proxy" doc I started from that as an example.

If you want to completely "remove" cookies you can:

```
location /path/ {
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
}
```

but I'm not sure this is what you want to do!

On the other hand, if you want to better control browser's cache too, you could re-set the vary header as you want:

```
location /path/ {
    proxy_hide_header Vary;
}
```

and you can even reset it to something else:

```
    add_header    Vary User-Agent;
```

Comment: From this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6552):

_The session framework is pretty cool in that it will automatically add a "Vary: Cookie" header to responses but only if it is accessed._

So, given the claim above and that session is accessed, the per-site cache would be sensitive cookie. GA cookie does change on every page access so it makes cache unusable.

Comment: @bmihelac my point was that if you have a frontend such as NGINX or VARNISH to manage your cache, you can simply tell him to ignore the VARY /or/ to ignore the GA cookie. In django, you can adjust the way cache is build with [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers). Without more information on your global architecture it's hard to be more specific, but in any case **you can** tune the cache to ignore all cookies, or some cookies. If your question was specific to no-frontend and FeinCMS you should make this clear!

Comment: If it is possible to tune per-site caching to ignore cookies I think that will be the answer to what Matt and me are looking for (did not found a way for it I admit). 

I am using nginx/uswgi, removing cookie (somehow) in nginx will also be solid solution for me.

Comment: @bmihelac I added some info on how to do caching in nginx ignoring the cookies. There are so many options to do caching (in a frontend, in django, etc..) that it would be difficult to show you all different ways or suggest a "best" solution. If you are using nginx this should work though (follow the specific uwsgi doc but get the details from the proxy_* one)!